# Position of "to" in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-order

Which of the following is grammatically correct and why?

> - I got less time to focus per course.
> - I got less time per course to focus on.

**Edit:** I want to convey the idea that because I took a higher number of courses I get less time to focus per course.

Comment: Both are grammatical. Between them, the choice should be on semantics and, importantly, the context. Each has its merits. If you have a context in mind, let us know the details.

Comment: @Kris see if the edit is helpful

Comment: I meant to say the question is whether you are speaking essentially about 'focus' or about 'course' -- Naturally, the second structure helps convey the meaning better.

Comment: _I have less time to focus on each course_ would obviate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second is less-than-ideal because of the weird placement of the preposition "on". Neither sentence makes the meaning clear. "I've got less time to focus on the courses individually because..." is a better option than either of the above.

Answer (score -1):

The position of adverbials (simple adverbs, prepositional phrases, etc.) is very free in English, and this isn't a matter of positioning the "*to*" block, but rather the adverbial. (In this case, "*per course*")

Both sentences are correct, as far as adverbial placement goes. However, "*got*" isn't a standalone verb, it is the past participle of get and this construction is obviously the Present Perfect, which requires an auxiliary verb, namely "*have*". Using got by itself is only used in some areas of the US, and in AAVE, so I would avoid using it in writing unless you intend to be speaking that way in a particular context. The got is also optional, but it's very frequently used in spoken English.

Also, "*to focus on*" means that you're focusing on the time, it requires an object, and in this case "*time*" is implied. I would remove it to keep the same meaning I believe you intended, like in the first sentence. So, in that case:

> I've/I have (got) less time to focus per course.
>
> I've/I have (got) less time per course to focus.

My intuition also says the second element (after the verb) would most likely be stressed when read, but the stress can be placed on either when spoken.

Comment: ahem, the past participle of "get" is "gotten" http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gotten

Comment: So is got: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/got

Comment: Also, "got" as the simple past of "get" is not just used in "some areas of the US" but pretty universally throughout the English-speaking world.

Comment: Got, standalone, to replace 'have' in the present tense, is used in some areas of the US, mostly all the time in AAVE, and in the UK in some areas too, my bad. I do not mean the simple past.

Comment: I'm not certain it's clear that the original questioner meant to use "got" in the present. I think the sentences make sense if interpreted as past tense. "I was so busy this semester with 3 more classes than last, and my schedule at work was so tight with my manager riding me so hard all the time. He didn't give me much time off for my studies. *I got less time to focus per course*."

Comment: That's very true. However I do notice that a lot of foreigners, especially those from Scandinavia, use this construction extremely often. I did assume, though. Perhaps I shouldn't have. It is worth pointing out though in case that is the case.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree that present tense "got" is problematic for formal written English and it is worth pointing out. I also agree that the sentences as presented are awkward, even with generous contextualization. Sadly, none of what we're saying addresses the questioner's actual query, which was about how to position the prepositional phrase "per course"

Comment: Yeah, we aren't. :P I think I addressed that fairly well at the start, the placement is free as far as my internal grammar is concerned, and as far as I know according to other formal grammars.

Comment: Apparently, the OP means other than *have* when using *got* -- think '*been given*' (That may not be very AmE, or even BrE, but it's very common where the OP is from). *I got a smaller piece than you.*

Comment: Yeah, I've realised that that's also another possible interpretation. Would you suggest that I edit my post?

Comment: Please also see the recent edit to the question.